# Accessing the parent object's size parameters in kivy widgets

Tags: python, kivy

Im learning Kivy and would like to center an object inside of a parent object.  I know I can access an object's own properties with the self keyword in the kv language, but is there a shortcut for accessing a parent widget's, say, size and position properties?  Both root.size and parent.size are failing for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A widget keeps a reference to its parent in `self.parent`. So you can just so `self.parent.size` or `self.parent.pos` or whatever.

Depending on what you're doing, it may be necessary or useful to make sure you check if `self.parent is None` first, so that your code doesn't fail for widgets with no parent.